# what could I do to fix my expo for React Native?

Tags: reactjs, expo

So, I deleted and reinstalled everything possible for React Native.  I began to get an error for the expo.  In the terminal a reoccurring error was .json is missing.  I don’t know how to fix this.  I’m new to React and using a Mac.  I was in the middle of a tutorial when it all stopped working.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post your full error log

Comment: I will.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please create package.json file in your project root folder and past below code and update according to your requirement like project name or description:

```js
{
  "name": "expo-template-tabs",
  "description": "The Tab Navigation project template includes several example screens.",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^31.0.5",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^31.0.0"
  }
}
```

Then run below command:
 - npm install

I hope it would help you out.

Comment: I will try it and let you know if it worked.  Thank you!